# Не могу обновить запись в Spring There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Подскажите почему при попытке обновить запись у меня выбивает There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).Удалить запись работает, а обновить почему-то не дает.
Вот мой WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll().and()
        .logout().permitAll();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(){
    UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                            .username("user")
                            .password("password")
                            .roles("USER")
                            .build();
    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
  }
  }
```

Вот форма редактирования записи

```
<h1>Редактирование книги</h1>
<div th:each="el : ${books} ">
  <form  method="post">
    <input type="text" th:value="${el.title}" name="title" placeholder="Введите название книги" > 
</br>
    <input type="text" th:value="${el.shortDescription}" name="shortDescription" placeholder="Введите 
краткий анонс (максимум 255 символов)" ></br>
    <textarea th:text="${el.description}"  name="description" placeholder="Введите ваше описание" 
 class="form-control" style="min-height: 300px"  /></br>
    <button type="submit" >Обновить</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

А вот контроллер

```
@GetMapping("/home/{id}/edit")
public String editBookPage(@PathVariable(value = "id") long bookId, Model model){
    if(bookRepository.existsById(bookId)){
        Optional<Book> findBook = bookRepository.findById(bookId);
        ArrayList<Book> result = new ArrayList<>();
        findBook.ifPresent(result :: add);
        model.addAttribute("books", result);
        return "edit";
    }else {
        return "redirect:/home";
    }
}

@PostMapping("/home/{id}/edit")
public String editBook(@PathVariable(value = "id") long bookId, @RequestParam String title,@RequestParam String genre,
                       @RequestParam String author, @RequestParam String shortDescription,
                       @RequestParam String description, Model model){
    //если такого id не существует то срабатывает orElseThrow();
    Book book = null;
    try {
        book = bookRepository.findById(bookId).orElseThrow(
                ()-> new Exception(String.valueOf(bookId)+"Такой id не найден")
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    book.setTitle(title);
    book.setGenre(genre);
    book.setAuthor(author);
    book.setShortDescription(shortDescription);
    book.setDescription(description);
    bookRepository.save(book);

    return "redirect: /home";
}
```

Подскажите что не так то?

Answer (score 0):

Все разобрался.Надо в классе WebSecurityConfig в методе configure в начало добавить: http.cors().disable()
.csrf().disable();

Answer (score 0):

Защита CSRF играет важную роль в spring security и не требует дополнительных усилий для обработки, поэтому нету никаких причин ее отключать.

На формумах есть затычка где CSRF дисейблят так:

```
http.csrf().disable();
```

Но, поскольку вы пользуетесь секьюрити фреймворком, то правильно будет сделать так:

- в каждый форм метод представления добавить поле, которое будет
  хранить CSRF токен:

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
  ```

Подробнее можете прочитать в книге spring in action 6 издание глава 5.3.4